# Access GIT via Cygwin but not via Git Bash?

Tags: git, ssh

I have installed msysgit - and I am trying to get it working. When I run a cygwin bash terminal - I can access my ssh via

> ssh user@host

When I try the same via a Git Bash

> git ls-remote user@host/path/to/git

I simply get a

> fatal: the remote end hung up

Any ideas what to do ?

Comment: I had all sorts of problems with git-bash. Cygwin just works.

Comment: "git ls-remote" is hardly the same as "ssh". Why don't you give ssh a try?

Comment: hi thanks. ive tried git ls-remote ssh://user@host/path/to/git - now i just get "fatal: remote end hung up". in cygwin bash - if i type ssh user@localhost - i login no probs. if i try it through a git bash - i get "fatal: remote end hung up". maybe i am doing something wrong with the ~/.ssh folder ? there is c:\cygwin\home\Mick\.ssh and c:\users\Mick\.ssh - i've got the same keys in both now ?

Answer (score 1):

you might want `git ls-remote user@host:path/to/git` -- notice the ':' (colon) between the hostname and the path, rather than a '/' slash.

To connect to a nonstandard port, add an entry to `~/.ssh/config` as follows

```
Host hostalias
HostName myhost.tld
Port 1234
User username
```

Comment: hey thanks. prob is that I have a port in there so path is - git ls-remote user@host:port/path/to/git

Comment: apparently, you have to edit the .ssh/config file: http://www.gelato.unsw.edu.au/archives/git/0512/13507.html

Comment: hey thx again :) yep edited that too :) i just cant get this darn thing to work.

Comment: you still getting the same "fatal: the remote end hung up" error?

Comment: yeah i had already edit my config file for the correct port. now i am just getting "permission denied" - i have the correct keys generated and put in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys for public key. private in the same folder

Comment: regenerated those - not i just get "remote end hung up" after i enter git ls-remote user@host etc

Comment: Maybe someone else has an answer.  I don't know.

Comment: ive tried git ls-remote ssh://user@host/path/to/git - now i just get "fatal: remote end hung up". in cygwin bash - if i type ssh user@localhost - i login no probs. if i try it through a git bash - i get "fatal: remote end hung up". maybe i am doing something wrong with the ~/.ssh folder ? there is c:\cygwin\home\Mick\.ssh and c:\users\Mick\.ssh - i've got the same keys in both now ?

Comment: if your ssh works in cygwin, I'd copy your  c:\cygwin\home\Mick\.ssh to  c:\cygwin\home\Mick\.ssh so that you know they're the same.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I have to add in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

```
Host my_git_ip
Port my_git_ssh_port
```

All is fine now !

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried doing:

```
$which git
```

In Bash Git?

I discovered mine was `/bin/git`, which is not correct.

Comment: Not necessarily. He would have gotten a 'could not find: git' error if that were true. /bin, /usr/local/bin, it depends on the environment.